# Sweet Alert does not work

Tags: javascript, alert, sweetalert

okay, first off, i am new to this. I was instructed to use sweet alert for the alerts in our project. I see to it that it will work so i made a simple one on a different file and made something like the code below, but it's not working. The Sweetalert is not showing. Did i miss something?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>

   <script>
    swal("Hello World");
   </script>

   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js" />
  </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are calling Sweet alert before it has been declared and linked to your HTML document.  Move the script reference to sweetalert.min.js to the head of your page. And also, script tags cannot be self closing. You need to close the script tag by doing `</script>`, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

   <script>
    swal("Hello World");
   </script>


  </body>
 </html>
```